# how to create 2 column layout with merging column?

Tags: android, gridview, tableview, tablelayout

how to create this kind of layout in android
i have tried using table layout. but getting error in creating this.
please check my code i am able to display images. 1 image in 1 row. but i want 2 small images in 1 row. and continues.

here is my code

```
private void getBannerList() {

    final Call<BannerList_Model> itemMainResponse = APIHandler.getApiService().bannerList(getFiledMapForItemList());

    itemMainResponse.enqueue(new Callback<BannerList_Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<BannerList_Model> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            BannerList_Model itemResponse = null;
            itemResponse = response.body();

            if (itemResponse == null) {
                UIUtils.showToast(getContext(), "Server Error !");
            } else {
                String msg = itemResponse.getMsg().toString();
                if (msg.equals("success")) {
                    userList = itemResponse.getBannerList();
                    if(userList != null) {
                        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tblBanner_list);
                        table.setColumnStretchable(0,true);
                        table.setColumnStretchable(1,true);

                        int tsize = userList.size();
                        TextView[] t1 = new TextView[tsize];
                        ImageView[] img = new ImageView[tsize];

                        for(int i=0; i<userList.size();i++)
                        {
                            TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
                            String banner_size = userList.get(i).getBannerSize().toString();


                                img[i] = new ImageView(getContext());
                                Picasso.with(getContext())
                                        .load(Constants.VIDEO_URL + userList.get(i).getBannerUrl())
                                        .into(img[i]);

                                row.addView(img[i]);

                                table.addView(row);

                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        }
    });
}
```

here is the video how i want layout
http://shrivivah.com/layout.mp4

if there is 2 small images than it will display in 1 row. 
if there is 2 medium or full size image than it will display in 1 row each.
if 1 small and 2 medum than 1 image per row to display.

layout image

[image]

Comment: Where is you image size control ?

Comment: din't code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are adding `TextView` to `TableRow`(row) but you didn't add row to `TableLayout`. Here is an example for what you need. You can set some margins and add button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you give me code without xml? i need to do it programatically

Comment: is your userlist's size 4 ?

Comment: no N number of list. if there is 2 small image than it will be in 2 column and if big image than 1 column.

Comment: How will you check if there is 2 small or 1 big image ? And where is you images ?

Comment: using json. i have passed banner size, small, full. image will be load from server. using api call.

Comment: Show your code pls so i can help you after your code.

Comment: here is json
{"msg":"success","banner_list":[{"banner_id":"3","title":"ghatlodia banner","banner_size":"small","banner_category":"4","banner_url":"banner\/dnbtmjpg.png","contact_no":"9999999999","time_limit":"2018-01-20"},{"banner_id":"4","title":"dfdf","banner_size":"medium","banner_category":"4","banner_url":"banner\/58dnbtmjpg.png","contact_no":"9999999999","time_limit":"2018-01-20"},{"banner_id":"5","title":"full image","banner_size":"full","banner_category":"7","banner_url":"banner\/ielts_academy.jpg","contact_no":"9999999999","time_limit":"2018-01-20"}]}

Comment: Show me your java code, not json. And update your question.

Comment: check now. i have added video also for layout.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.tops.stackoverflow.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llShortcutParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes, but i want to create dynamically. there will be list of items.

Comment: Can u use  layout_span=2 property for textview for the row 2 and 3